# Why EXPLAIN mysql query return different depending on the environment

Tags: mysql, sql-execution-plan

I'm using same mysql query But, The execution result differs depending on the environment.

There are A and B environments, and the differences between them that I understand are as follows

A.

```
mysql Version: 5.7.38
server: docker container in AWS EC2
```

B.

```
mysql version: 5.7.23-log
server: AWS RDS
```

index is the same and each row in the table is different.

The query executed is as follows.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT  messages.member_id, messages.sub_id, MAX(messages.id) AS id FROM `messages` INNER JOIN `members` ON `members`.`id` = `messages`.`member_id` WHERE `messages`.`xx_id` = 1111 GROUP BY `messages`.`member_id`, `messages`.`sub_id`  ORDER BY MAX(messages.created_at) DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0 \G
```

Each EXPLAIN result is different as follows.

A:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: messages
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_messages_on_member_id,index_on_message_xx_id_created_at,index_messages_on_member_id_and_sub_id
          key: index_on_message_xx_id_created_at
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 268822
     filtered: 16.66
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: members
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: db1.messages.member_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 5.00
        Extra: Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

B:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: members
   partitions: NULL
         type: range
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: NULL
         rows: 606172
     filtered: 0.90
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: messages
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: index_messages_on_member_id,index_on_message_xx_id_created_at,index_messages_on_member_id_and_sub_id
          key: index_messages_on_member_id_and_sub_id
      key_len: 4
          ref: db2.members.id
         rows: 14
     filtered: 0.50
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
2 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

Why does EXPLAIN MySQL query return different depending on the environment?

Are the following reasons relevant?

1. Because MySQL version is different
2. Because the table rows are different depending on the environment

Comment: depending on the data in the environment, the stats will vary

Comment: MySql tries to optimice the query and uses index or not (or uses different indexes) depending on the amount of data you have and some other values in your DB. So, if you have different data in your 2 environments, even if tables/indexes/query are equal, you can get diferent execution plan depending on the data